# Use WMP to sync and transcode into MP4

Tags: windows-media-player, mp4

Can WMP be configured or extended to transcode files to MP4 when syncing to an external device?

In particular, I'd like to sync videos to my Sony NWZ-S616F walkman.

Video:

- AVC (H.264/AVC)

  - Profile: Baseline Profile
  - Level: Max. 1.3
  - Bitrate: Max. 768 kbps
- MPEG-4

  - Profile: Simple Profile
  - Bit rate: Max. 2,500 kbps
- Frame rate: Max. 30 fps
- Resolution: Max. QVGA (320 x 240)

Audio:

- AAC-LC

  - Channel number: Max. 2 channels
  - Sampling frequency: 24, 32, 44.1, 48 kHz
  - Bit rate: Max. 288 kbps per 1 channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears a third party conversion application is required to convert video into a format supported by the Sony Walkman.

I've tried the [iWisoft Free Video Converter](http://www.iwisoft.com/videoconverter/) which has a conversion profile called "Walkman Video (*.mp4)".

[image]